# WordPress displays post on subcategory only

Tags: posts, categories, query-posts

I'm using WordPress on developing a site and a self-made template. I got 1 page to display all categories with its post. This is what I want to do:

- Main Category

  - subcategory1

    - post 1
    - subcategory1.2

      - post 1.2.1
      - post 1.2.2
  - subcategory2
  - subcategory3

I used `wp_link_category()` to display the category and I searched how to display category with post but the problem is: the post from subcategory 1.2 is also displayed on subcategory 1.

- Main Category

  - subcategory1

    - post 1
    - post 1.2.1
    - post 1.2.2
    - subcategory1.2

      - post 1.2.1
      - post 1.2.2
  - subcategory2
  - subcategory3

How can I remove the post from subcategory 1.2 on subcategory 1?

Here's the code I copied and pasted from StackOverflow:

```
$categories =  get_categories('child_of=4');  
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
    //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
    echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';   
    }  
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I remove the post from subcategory 1.2 on subcategory 1?

Use the `'category__in'` argument parameter instead of the `'cat'` parameter.

Here is a user function that does what you want.

```
/**
 * Category post list.
 *
 * An unordered list of category posts links. Posts in subcategories
 * are not listed in parent category. Skips categories with no posts.
 *
 * @param $parent_category The parent category to start with. Defaults to 0.
 */
function wpse_113987_category_post_list( $parent_category = 0 ) {

    $post_list_format = '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>';

    // Step through each category object.
    foreach ( get_categories( "child_of=$parent_category" )  as $category ) {

        $category_posts = get_posts( array(
            // Do not include posts in sub categories.
            'category__in'  => array( $category->term_id ),
        ) );

        // Skip categories with no posts.
        if ( empty( $category_posts ) )
            continue;

        echo "<h2>$category->name</h2>\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";

        // Step through each post object.
        foreach ( $category_posts as $post ) {
            printf( $post_list_format, get_permalink( $post->ID ), get_the_title( $post->ID ) );
        }

        echo "\n</ul><!-- end $category->name -->\n";
    }
}
```

To call it, use:

```
wpse_113987_category_post_list( 4 );
```